# How to convert a block level element to inline via CSS

Tags: css

Let's say I have this content:

```
<div class="entry">
<p>I want to display <br /><h2>heading level elements like this</h2>
<p> as inline elements on the same line with the text that preceded them as well as...</p>
<p>the text that<br />
<h3>(another heading element)</h3>
<p>, follows them...</p>
</p></p>
</div>
```

And I want the heading elements to appear inline in the text, just as if they were simply bold text, the same size as the content.

Any ideas what CSS would accomplish this with the above example, without altering the content?

Comment: first you have to search it in google & stackoverflow. It's basic question

Answer (score 5):

Use the `display:inline` property:

```
.entry h2,  /* Combining two selectors: h2/h3 as a child of class=entry */
.entry h3 {
    display: inline;
}
```

See also: [MDN, CSS display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`. Use the latter if you want to set the width or height on the element. `inline-block` behaves like a `block` element except that it renders it inline.

```
.entry h2, .entry h3 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: `<img>` is an example of something that is `display: inline-block` by default.  (It's probably not what you want for text.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
 h3{display:inline; }
```

Or you can put a span instead and give it the same style as H3

```
<div class="entry">
<p>I want to display <br /><h2>heading level elements like this</h2>
<p> as inline elements on the same line with the text that preceded them as well as...</p>
<p>the text that<br />
<span class="h3Like">(another heading element)</span>
<p>, follows them...</p>
</p></p>
</div>
```

And add css like this

```
.h3Like{font-size:15px;font-weight:bold}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>block to inline</title>
    <style>
         h1 {
            display: inline;
         }
         span {
            display: block;
         }
    
    </style>

</head>
<body>
       
       <p>lorem itaque <h1>block element to inline</h1> quia <p>

       <p>lorem res <span>inline to block </span> reprehenderit, anime</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add some explanation about how your code works

Comment: As we  know the h1 is a block element which I have used inside <P> tag but in the style I have made it as the inline element so now h1 in <p> tag becomes inline element that the reason in the output <h1> is not starting a new line. Its just continuing in as a inline element.   AND you can see that I have a <span> in my <p> tag but I have now made it as block so now <span> will create a new line because it is a block element now.